# getchar() in a while loop Question

Tags: c, loops, getchar

I am a newbee writing a C program for school where the input is redirected to a file. I am to use `getchar()` only to retrieve the information. I am using Windows Visual 2008 and I cannot figure out why my code will not exit the loop. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
while (rec != 'EOF')
{
    while (rec != '\n')
    { 
        variable=getchar;
        printf ("this is variable %c");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while (rec != EOF)
{
     rec=getchar();
     if((rec != '\n') && (rec != EOF)){     
          printf ("this is variable %c\n",rec);
     }
}
```

Comment: You left the mistakes on `getchar` without `()` and printf that doesn't bind the `%c` to `rec`. You've set the value of `rec` in a better place though.

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = 0;
while (c != EOF) {
    c = getchar();

    if (c == '\n')
        break;

    printf("c:%c\n", c);
}
```

Comment: That stops at the first `\n`.  I'm not sure that is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what is really needed.  If you want to print every character except the new lines, you want something like:

```
int c = getchar(); // Note c is defined as an int otherwise the loop condition is broken
while (c != EOF)
{
    if (c != `\n`)
    {
        printf("c:%c\n", c);
    }
    c = getchar();
}
```

If you just want the characters on the first line:

```
int c = getchar();
while (c != EOF && c != `\n`)
{
    printf("c:%c\n", c);
    c = getchar();
}
```